# How to create an autosize SVG path with Raphael JS?

Tags: svg, raphael

I don't understand the way Raphael or SVG works.

I want to create a map of germany, using SVG and Raphael. I have the paths of each administrative area and creation works, but the result got an own size.

I mean, if I tell Raphael being 300x300px and add some paths the objects generated by paths are larger.

**Code:**

```
var paper = new Raphael(document.getElementById('svnInnerGroup'), 300, 300);
paper.path('...');
```

**Result:** I get a 300x300 pixel SVG graphic (this is good), with the upper left corner of germany (this is not good). I expect that the map of germany would fit to the given size.

Maybe I don't understand the concept, I hope you can help me.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I have found my mistake! Such SVG graphics always need a "viewbox", which defines the beginning and ending of the document. When I copy any paths from any file, I need to copy and use the viewbox too.

This is how you can set the viewbox with raphael:

```
paper.canvas.setAttribute("viewBox", "0 0 591 800");
```

Thanks!

Comment: Yes, but the result is different. The setViewBox method lets the object appears on the left. The canvas.setAttribute method put it to center.